# Issues getting new httpChallenge working in Traefik 1.5.0-rc5

Tags: ssl, docker, traefik

In trying to upgrade to the latest traefik version to be able to generate TLS certs from LetsEncrypt, I've come across a problem when it comes to cert generation time.

This worked previously on `traefik:1.4` using the `acme.ondemand` flag and the other settings (minus the `httpChallenge` keys of course).

## Config:

```
traefik:
  image: traefik:1.5.0-rc5-alpine
  ports:
    - 80:80/tcp
    - 443:443/tcp
  command:
    - --web
    - --rancher
    - --rancher.metadata
    - --acme
    - --acme.email=my@email.com
    - --acme.onhostrule
    - --acme.httpchallenge
    - --acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=http
    - --acme.entrypoint=https
    - --acme.storage=/data/acme.json
    - --entryPoints=Name:http Address::80 Redirect.EntryPoint:https
    - --entryPoints=Name:https Address::443 TLS
    - --accesslog
    - --accesslog.format=json
    - --debug
```

## Openssl s_client result of not-yet-existant cert

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=0 /CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
  i:/CN=TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
---
...
Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
```

## Traefik logs

`time="2018-01-16T19:17:49Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate to validate [mysite.com]..."
time="2018-01-16T19:17:49Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains [mysite.com], get ACME certificate."
time="2018-01-16T19:17:49Z" level=debug msg="Looking for an existing ACME challenge for mysite.com..."
time="2018-01-16T19:17:49Z" level=debug msg="No certificate found or generated for mysite.com"`

Attempting to narrow down to just a toml file with the same config to determine if that's the problem or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that in the end, the problem was actually that I didn't have a container matching the host that I was testing against, running in my cluster.

I was using `openssl s_client -connect host:443 -servername mysite.com`, however I didn't realize that in the cluster I was targeting, there was no container with a label of `traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mysite.com`.

Therefore, I was just getting a 404 from traefik's perspective, which ended up using the default traefik cert.  When curl'ing - I never got the 404 since I never got past the TLS handshake.

Answer (score 0):

The `onHostRule` try to challenge an ACME cert when you have a HostRule on a frontend with the same Entrypoint as ACME EntryPoint.

When new frontend are loaded, they use the entrypoint you specify or the `defaultEntrypoints`.

Here:
Your `defaultEntrypoints` is `http`
Your ACME EntryPoint is `https`

So when your frontent is created, it is assigned to `http`, that's why you don't have any challenge.

Then, your logs only say that when you try to access https://example.com, Træfik try to find certificate in already challenged ACME cert.

In order to fix, you need to specify `defaultEntrypoints` with `https` (and `http` if you need it)

Comment: Thanks Julien!  So on each of my target hosts - I have the following labels set up:

    `traefik.port: '9000'
    traefik.frontend.rule: Host:app.${TARGET_DOMAIN}
    traefik.frontend.entryPoints: http,https`

I would think that would create and cover the acme entrypoint for the challenge, is that right or no?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the snippet end of `traefik.toml`, it may help you

```
[docker]
  endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
  watch = true
```

Comment: I detailed the solution in the accepted answer (Well, the problem I was having at least)