# Certificate not automatically created - Docker-Compose, Traefik, Let's Encrypt,

Tags: docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

I have set up my first home-docker-stack:

1. DDNS account --> No chance to get subdomains --> Use ports.
2. Configure a https-proxy so that https-configuration is not required for each container --> Use traefik.

Now I have a traefik.toml with the following content:

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
logLevel = "DEBUG"
debug = true

[web]
address = ":8080"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "MY_EMAIL_ADDRESS"
storage = "/etc/traefik/acme/acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
onDemand = true
OnHostRule = false

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"

[docker]
domain = "MY_DOMAIN"
watch = true
```

And a docker-compose.yml looking as follows:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.1
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SOMEPASSWORD
    env_file:
      - db.env

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:apache
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8001:80"
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=SOMEPASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - default
      - traefik-net
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.port=8001"
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5-alpine
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-net
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/traefik/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml:ro
      - /home/traefik/acme:/etc/traefik/acme
    privileged: true
    container_name: traefik

volumes:
  db:

networks:
  traefik-net:
```

If I now try to reach my traefik-instance as follows:

```
https://MY_DOMAIN/
```

The client returns (untrusted self signed certificate):

```
Dem Zertifikat wird nicht vertraut, weil es vom Aussteller selbst signiert wurde.
```

The traefik log contains:

```
traefik      | time="2018-03-19T13:29:29Z" level=debug msg="Looking for provided certificate to validate MY_DOMAIN..." 
traefik      | time="2018-03-19T13:29:29Z" level=debug msg="No provided certificate found for domains MY_DOMAIN, get ACME certificate." 
traefik      | time="2018-03-19T13:29:29Z" level=debug msg="Looking for an existing ACME challenge for MY_DOMAIN..." 
traefik      | time="2018-03-19T13:29:29Z" level=debug msg="http2: server: error reading preface from client 80.129.18.33:44700: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority"
```

Why might the generation of the certificate not start? What do I have to fix?

Comment: The same problem, it works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504793/2599460

Answer (score 0):

Traefik will access your container through the docker network, in the docker network the ports you have set in the `ports` mapping in the docker-compose file means nothing. `ports` is just to map the container port to one of the hosts ports.

So the port that you should tell traefik to use (through the labels) is `80`, the port that the webserver listens to. And you could remove the port mapping, because that's just to the host, if Traefik have ports open for http, it will route the requests to your container (through the exposed port, which should be 80).

As long as your container is in the network, the `exposed` ports will be available for all other containers in the network.

---

Another note:

You are in the docker-compose file using a 3.x version. All 3.x versions are `swarm` specific, so stick to 2.x for none-swarm files.